# How do I format date and time on ssrs report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

on SSRS report I need to show `todays date and current time`

i tried this `=FormatDateTime(Now,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")` but this is not working for me giving an error.

Anyone please help me for `expression` ?

I want output display like `4/12/2013 12:05 PM`

Answer (score 278, accepted):

```
=Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

Output:

```
04/12/2013 05:09 PM
```

Full list of format options might be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Kudos to @MattGibson.

Comment: Possible `Format()` strings are described in this article: [Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz.aspx); I figured I'd mention that as it was what I was looking for when I arrived here!

Answer (score 22):

If the date and time is in its own cell (aka textbox), then you should look at applying the format to the entire textbox. This will create cleaner exports to other formats; in particular, the value will export as a datetime value to Excel instead of a string.

Use the properties pane or dialog to set the format for the textbox to "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"

I would only use Ian's answer if the datetime is being concatenated with another string.

Comment: Little addon for people that may find this answer: You set the format to `="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"`. If you forget the `=`, every cell will just have `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"` as text.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy – 10/02/2008                  

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02           

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) -- dd mon yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) -- mon dd, yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) -- hh:mm:ss

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) -- mm-dd-yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) -- yyyy/mm/dd

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) -- yyyymmdd

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) -- dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 114) -- hh:mm:ss:mmm(24h)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
```

Comment: Formatting should never be done in the datbase. It creates all kind of problems (sorting, filtering etc.) It should only be done on the presentation layer (in this case, in the report). This solution is not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

I am using following in SSRS 2005

```
=Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"MM-dd-yyyy" & " ") 
& CStr(Hour(Globals!ExecutionTime))  & ":"
& CStr(Minute(Globals!ExecutionTime))
```

Or

```
=Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"MM-dd-yyyy" & " ") 
& Right("00" & CStr(Hour(Globals!ExecutionTime)), 2)
& ":"
& Right("00" & CStr(Minute(Globals!ExecutionTime)), 2)
```

OR:

```
=Format(CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm.ss")
```

OR

```
=Format(CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm.ss")
```

Comment: Both can look simpler:
`=Format(CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm.ss")`
 or 
`=Format(CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm.ss")`

Answer (score 6):

In SSRS 2016 There is an option under the properties header "Localization" called "`Calendar`", if you click on this it gives you these 2 options:

- Gregorian          (dd/mm/yyyy)
- GregorianUSEnglish (MM/dd/yyyy)

This works brilliantly when referencing data from a tables aswell

alternatively if this does not work for you, specify one of these formats under "Number" and in the cell "`Format`":

`dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 2):

The following is how I do it using Visual Studio 2017 for an RDL targetted for SSRS 2017:

Right-click on the field in the textbox on the design surface and choose **Placeholder Properties**.  Choose the **Number** panel and click on **Date** in the **Category** listbox, then select the formatting you are looking for in the **Type** listbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the empty spot on the report away from any table and then look in properties, one of the Misc fields is called Language which allows you to pick which Language you would like to set, which after doing so can play around with this

```
=FormatDateTime(now,x)
```

Which `x` can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 1):

If you want date and time separate then use below expressions: 
[Date and Time Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBWP8.png)

**Expression1** for current date : **=formatdatetime(today)** 
its return date is = 11/15/2016

**Expression2** for current time : **=CDate(Now).ToString("hh:mm tt")**
its return time is = 3:44 PM

This report printed on **Expression1**  at **Expression2**

Output will be : 
[Output of Both Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHtZq.png)

This report printed on **11/15/2016**  at **3:44 PM**

Comment: Thanks, I tried using Expression2, but it's showing 03:44 PM. Is there a way to make it show 3:44 PM and drop the leading 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
=Replace(Format(CDate(Now()),"MM.dd.yyyy"), ".", "/")
```

Answer (score 1):

First go to your control panel , select Date , time and Number Format . Now select English(United Kingdom) from the drop down list.

Make sure the shor date field is equal to 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Press Apply. Now go to SSRS and right click on the report in the empty space and select properties.

If you are using visual studio then set Language property equal to =User!Language.

If you are using Report Builder then Language property will appear in Localization section.

Answer (score -4):

hi friend please try this expression your report

```
="Page " + Globals!PageNumber.ToString() + " of " + Globals!OverallTotalPages.ToString() + vbcrlf + "Generated: " + Globals!ExecutionTime.ToString()
```

Comment: Folks, this does answer the question. The date is at the far right end of the expression. The extra info is useful too. Deserves more up votes imo.